# Need C# code to capture response from network tab in devtool.. in edge browser

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge, devtools

I need C# code to capture response from network tab in devtool.. in edge browser

```
IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(@"C:/SS/Selenium/C#/edgedriver_win32");
       
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
// Navigate to the login page
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.demoblaze.com/");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
// Locate the login elements and perform login
driver.FindElement(By.Id("login2")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(3500);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginusername")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(3500);
// locate login elements
driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginusername")).SendKeys("testuser321a"); Thread.Sleep(3500);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginpassword")).SendKeys("testuser"); Thread.Sleep(3500); Console.WriteLine("test here asdfasdfg");
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"logInModal\"]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")).Click(); Thread.Sleep(3500);
//// click the login button
//loginbutton.Click();
Thread.Sleep(3500);
Console.WriteLine("test here 1324");

var devTools = (OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.IDevTools)driver;
OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.IDevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
var domains = session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<DevToolsSessionDomains>();
domains.Network.ResponseReceived += ResponseReceivedHandler;
System.Threading.Tasks.Task task = domains.Network.Enable(new Network.EnableCommandSettings());
task.Wait();


void ResponseReceivedHandler(object sender, Network.ResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Status: {e.Response.Status} : {e.Response.StatusText} | File: {e.Response.MimeType} | Url: {e.Response.Url}");
}
```

Getting below error on this line of code:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.IDevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
```

Error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Unexpected error creating WebSocket DevTools session.'
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

using: Selenium.WebDriver Version="4.6.0"
and .Net6.0

Answer (score 0):

Tested in `Selenium 4.17.0` + `.Net 6.0` + `Microsoft Edge Driver 121.0.2277.112`, your code did not throw 'Unexpected error creating WebSocket DevTools session.' You can upgrade your Selenium version to the latest and test again.

The reason why you can't get the response is you are trying to receive response after the navigation completed and everything was fully loaded. No response is expected to be captured.

You only need to either:

1. Move the navigation actions down right after `task.Wait()`
2. Or use `driver.Navigate().Refresh()` after `task.Wait()`, in order to refresh the page to recapture the response.

Comment: Thanks for your solution ...Now I am not getting error ..but there is no result or no response getting displayed... kindly let know if you were able to get the response .. Any solve is appreciated ..thanks..

Comment: @sriramsrinivasan I have explained the reason and shared some suggestions. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments..
Getting response like below  .... but wanted to capture the token that is present in the response of "check" api .. looks like I am not getting that .. Kindly let know... thanks a lot
Status: 200 :  | File: text/html | Url: https://www.demoblaze.com/ | test == 'OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V121.Network.Response'
Status: 200 :  | File: image/jpeg | Url: https://www.demoblaze.com/Samsung1.jpg | test == 'OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V121.Network.Response'

Comment: Just want to capture the entire response body.. thanks

Comment: Is it possible to get response body of all the api's called ..any help is appreciated..thanks

Comment: @sriramsrinivasan For response body, you can try Network.getResponseBody: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-getResponseBody

Comment: thanks for your help.. able to capture response now..

Comment: Sure sir ..will let them know